# Does a photo copyright have an expiration date?

Tags: legal, copyright, patents

The term of a new patent is 20 years from the date on which the application for the patent was filed in the United States. Is there something like that to photo copyright?

Comment: The photo does not have an expiration date, but the copyright held on that photo does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This is not legal advice!**

According to [this FAQ](https://www.copyright.gov/help/faq/faq-duration.html) from U.S. Copyright Office copyright protection lasts for the life of the author plus an additional 70 years.
Also get in mind this:

> work made for hire, the copyright endures for a term of 95 years from
> the year of its first publication or a term of 120 years from the year
> of its creation, whichever expires first

P.S. The law differ from country to country so if you explicitly mention the country of your interest you may get more precise answers.
Here is [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries%27_copyright_lengths) with the expiration times of copyright in different countries.

Comment: Very nice and quick answer. Thanks @Romeo Ninov.

Comment: I think the laws are similar among the countries that recognize copyrights, as the foundation was laid in international conventions, such as The Universal Copyright Convention (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Copyright_Convention) and the Berne Convention (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention).
Also remember that specific reproductions may have different copyrights from the original. E.g. if another person than the original photographer did the retouching, the copyrights for the retouched version could lie with the retoucher.

Comment: @Pete, nevertheless the length differ. You can check here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries%27_copyright_lengths. Also for example in EU you get copyright in the moment you take a photo which is not the case in US (AFAIK)

Comment: According to this link, you do have the copyright in the US when the "work is created", but you need to register the work in order to take legal action in case of copyright infringements: https://wellsiplaw.com/how-and-why-to-register-copyright-in-your-work/

Comment: @Pete, right. But in EU you do not need to register it. I am sure in other countries these details also differ. :)

Comment: Ok @Pete. But does the copyright on the retouched version need any approval from the original photographer?

Comment: @zewill This seems like you asking a new question If so, it is better to pose it as a new question and not just in the comments.

Comment: @Pete You don't have to register it to seek *actual* damages from an infringer. You do need to register it to seek *punitive* damages from copyright infringement.

Comment: @zewill That depends on whether it is considered a "derivative work" or not. The only way you'll know in a specific instance is to let a judge decide after you're in court. But then an appeals court could reverse that decision or not.

Comment: @zewill We have a number of existing questions that cover most of this. Please search for terms such as "derivative work", "copyright length", etc. to find them.